# Python: Convert matrices to permutations table

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, matrix

Given a set of ids, I need to get the values from a matrix (time A & B) for each id combination, and create a dataframe appending the values for all the permutations.

I have been able to do it by creating the permutations dataframe and then iterating through it while looking & filling the values. However I need to do this for ~3000 ids, not 3, and I don't know how to do it efficiently.

Can I generate a Time A/B dataframe as my example without having to iterate through 9000000* rows? I know I shouldn't be iterating though a dataframe however I haven't found an alternative yet.

Ids (3):

```
[15, 24, 38]
```

Time A matrix (3x3):

```
id          15        24      38
15          0         1.8     1.7
24          1.2       0       1.9
38          1.5       1.3     0
```

Time B matrix (3x3):

```
id          15        24      38
15          0         88.7    87.3
24          42.2      0       32.7
38          65.6      13.5    0
```

Time A/B dataframe (6):

```
id_start    id_end    A       B
15          24        1.8     88.7
15          38        1.9     32.7
24          15        1.2     42.2
24          38        1.9     65.6
38          15        1.5     65.6
38          24        1.3     13.5
```

Comment: @QuangHoang correct, it was a typo.

Comment: Another note, is `TimeA` a numpy array and the `id` are just there for illustration purpose? Or is `TimeA` a dataframe indexed/columned by `ids`?

Comment: @QuangHoang the 2nd, it's a panda's dataframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
# drop set_index('id') if `id` is already index
(pd.concat([timeA.set_index('id').stack().to_frame(name='A'),
           timeB.set_index('id').stack().to_frame(name='B')], axis=1)
   .rename_axis(index=['id_start','id_end'])
   .query('id_start != id_end')
   .reset_index()
)
```

Output:

```
   id_start  id_end    A     B
1        15      24  1.8  88.7
2        15      38  1.7  87.3
3        24      15  1.2  42.2
5        24      38  1.9  32.7
6        38      15  1.5  65.6
7        38      24  1.3  13.5
```